# Converting custom text style code to html

Tags: javascript

I have example string which uses custom style codes for text, the combinations are always in 2 words first word is either N or B (Normal, Bold) and second word is L or R or C (Left, Right, Center). So combinations are in this format NL, BL etc...

Now i want to use CKEditor and display this with HTML codes as CKEditor requires them. What would you suggest how to tackle this? I tried with splitting string based on characters like this:

```
var fields = contentFromDB.split(/(NL|BL|NR|BR|NC|BC)/g);
```

and than in for loop tackle the string with ifs:

```
if(fields[i] = ("NL")) {
} else if(fields[i] = ("BL")) {
    convertedString += "<b>"
} else if(fields[i] = ("NR")) {
} else if(fields[i] = ("BR")) {
}
```

But the thing is i should close tag before the other one starts. So any tips how would you guys do this thing?

Comment: What do you mean by "i should close tag before the other one starts"? Could you include example of input and the desired output on your question?

Comment: Sure following: NLCheck out our new webpage
NLon www.example.com
NLand check out this news
NL
BLHave a great day

Should convert to: <p>Check out our new webpage<br />on www.example.com<br />and check out this news<br /><br /><strong>Have a great day</strong></p>

Comment: Include that in your question and format it so it's easier to read. One more thing: Please include at least one instance of every possible identifier in your example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should parse the identifier letter by letter by using 2 switch statement as to reduce the code and flip the order of parsing to be able to close the tag accordingly

```js
var contentFromDB = "";
contentFromDB += "NLLorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
contentFromDB += "BLLorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
contentFromDB += "NCLorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
contentFromDB += "BCLorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
contentFromDB += "NRLorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
contentFromDB += "BRLorem ipsum dolor sit amet";
var fields = contentFromDB.split(/(NL|BL|NR|BR|NC|BC)/g);
var convertedString = "";
for(let i = 0; i<fields.length; i++){
  let currentIdentifier = fields[i];
  if(currentIdentifier.trim() == "") continue;
  switch(currentIdentifier[1]){
    case "L":
      convertedString += "<p>";
      break;
    case "C":
      convertedString += "<p align='center'>";
      break;
    case "R":
      convertedString += "<p align='right'>";
  }
  // Increase the loop walker to be able to get
  // The text and close the tag accordingly
  i++;
  switch(currentIdentifier[0]){
    case "N":
      convertedString += fields[i] + "</p>";
      break;
    case "B":
      convertedString += "<b>" + fields[i] + "</b></p>";
      break;
  }
}
document.write(convertedString);
```

```html
Result of parsing:
```